# Iterating over all the keys of a map

Tags: loops, dictionary, go

Is there a way to get a list of all the keys in a Go language map?  The number of elements is given by `len()`, but if I have a map like:

```
m := map[string]string{ "key1":"val1", "key2":"val2" };
```

How do I iterate over all the keys?

Answer (score 752, accepted):

https://play.golang.org/p/JGZ7mN0-U-

```
for k, v := range m { 
    fmt.Printf("key[%s] value[%s]\n", k, v)
}
```

or

```
for k := range m {
    fmt.Printf("key[%s] value[%s]\n", k, m[k])
}
```

[Go language specs for `for` statements](http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements) specifies that the first value is the key, the second variable is the value, but doesn't have to be present.

Comment: As a possible gotcha, note that the order of the iteration is undefined. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/YfDxpkI34hY/4pktJI2ytusJ

Comment: Sudhir: golang language spec explicitly defines maps as having undefined ordering of keys. Furthermore, since Go 1, key order is intentionally randomized between runs to prevent dependency on any perceived order.

Comment: Note that this is not a mutable iteration, which is to say deleting a key will require you to restart the iteration.

Comment: Also for small data sets, map order could be predictable.

Answer (score 21):

Here's some easy way to get `slice` of the map-keys.

```
// Return keys of the given map
func Keys(m map[string]interface{}) (keys []string) {
    for k := range m {
        keys = append(keys, k)
    }
    return keys
}

// use `Keys` func
func main() {
    m := map[string]interface{}{
        "foo": 1,
        "bar": true,
        "baz": "baz",
    }
    fmt.Println(Keys(m)) // [foo bar baz]
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for the `Keys` function to take a map with keys of any type, not just strings?

Comment: `func Keys(m map[interface{}]interface{}) (keys []interface{})`, @RobertT.McGibbon you need to change the function "prototype"

Comment: @ArielM. That would only work for the exact type `map[interface{}]interface{}`. Go does not support generics. You can't create a function with a `map` parameter which accepts maps with different key types.

Comment: is there anyway I can put an if condition on k in the for loop and change its value? means : 


Keys(m map[string]interface{}) (keys []string) {
for k := range m {
 if k = "abc" {
  k = "dce"
 }
 keys = append(keys, k)
}
return keys
}

Answer (score 19):

> Is there a way to get a list of all the keys in a Go language map?

```
ks := reflect.ValueOf(m).MapKeys()
```

> how do I iterate over all the keys?

Use the accepted answer:

```
for _, k := range m { ... }
```

Comment: I think you meant `for _, k := range v.MapKeys()`, since in your example, `k` would be the int index of the slice of keys

Answer (score 6):

**A Type agnostic solution:**

```
for _, key := range reflect.ValueOf(yourMap).MapKeys() {
    value := yourMap.MapIndex(key).Interface()
    fmt.Println("Key:", key, "Value:", value)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using Generics:

```
func Keys[K comparable, V any](m map[K]V) []K {
    keys := make([]K, 0, len(m))

    for k := range m {
        keys = append(keys, k)
    }

    return keys
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For **sorted keys of map[string]string**.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
)

func main() {
    m := map[string]string{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}
    sortStringMap(m)
}

// sortStringMap prints the [string]string as keys sorted
func sortStringMap(m map[string]string) {
    var keys []string
    for key := range m {
        keys = append(keys, key)
    }
    sort.Strings(keys)  // sort the keys
    for _, key := range keys {
        fmt.Printf("%s\t:%s\n", key, m[key])
    }
}
```

output:

```
key1    :val1
key2    :val2
```