# How to iterate over all the elements of a map in Go?

Tags: dictionary, go

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Iterating over all the keys of a golang map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841443/iterating-over-all-the-keys-of-a-golang-map)

Could somebody having used go tell me how to look through all element of a map data structure, or it could not be traversed?

Comment: OK,i flag it as duplicate one

Answer (score 2):

```
for key, value := range m { /* do stuff here */ }
```

This is a duplicate as nemo said.