# Please help me figure out how to parse this json file

Tags: json, parsing, go

I'm just starting to learn go.

This is the file I need to parse:

```
{ 
    "people": {
        "asd": {
            "name": "Alex",
            "id": 0,
            "s": "m"
        },
        "fda": {
            "name": "Mike",
            "id": 1,
            "s": "m"
        },
        "fg2": {
            "name": "Rosa",
            "id": 3,
            "s": "f",
            "Childs" :
            [
                {
                    "name": "Bob",
                    "age": 1,
                    "s": "m"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Maria",
                    "age": 2,
                    "s": "f"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

asd, fda, fg2 are some kind of identifiers consisting of a random set of characters.

First of all, I couldn't describe the structure for this file, I was confused by these random identifiers.

And I did this:

```
type people {
    People *map[string]interface{} `json:"people"`
}
```

So I'm trying to read and parse this file and just got stuck.
This is my code:

```
package main

import "encoding/json"
import "io/ioutil"
import "log"
import "fmt"

type people struct {
    People map[string]interface{} `json:"people"`
}

func main() {

    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./people.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error:", err)
    }

    var data people

    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(file), &data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error:", err)
    }

    //fmt.Println(data.people)//

    fmt.Println(data)
    //  for i := 0; i < len(data); i++ {//here the compiler throws error...
    //    fmt.Println("name: ", data[i].name)//#@!o_0
    //  }
  }
```

The error is: invalid operation: data[i] (type people does not support indexing).

Please help me sort out and print the names of these people, as well as the names of their children.

```
Alex
Mike
Rosa
    Bob
    Maria
```

Comment: The errors that he compiler throws are more descriptive than `#@!o_0`, and will tell you exactly what is wrong there. `data` probably looks strange because you don't need a pointer to a map, the struct itself is addressable.

Comment: @JimB thank you, I removed the " * " character from the structure description. And the error is: invalid operation: data[i] (type people does not support indexing). Please tell me how do i work with this structure...

Comment: You can't iterate over `data` or index it, because it's a struct with a single field called `People`.

Comment: @JimB, can you tell me how to describe the structure for such a file?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the javascript presented here is an object with a single field named `"people"`, so this structure will work.

Comment: @JimB, how do I enumerate elements with these random IDs?

Comment: @Evgeny Does [Iterating over all the keys of a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841443/iterating-over-all-the-keys-of-a-map) answer your question?

Comment: @CeriseLimón
 
 for k := range data.People {
  fmt.Printf("%s\n", data.People[k]["name"])//invalid operation: data.People[k]["name"] (type interface {} does not support indexing)
 }
 
Isn't there an easy way to do what I need to do? :(

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/45EVMf5RPgb
to give you some idea.

Comment: @gipsy, thank you!
Thank you all! I have solved this task.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do that this way. Update: sort the name.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "sort"
)

type people struct {
    People map[string]interface{} `json:"people"`
}

type Node struct {
    Name     string
    Space    int
    Children *[]Node
}

func sortAndPrint(ans []Node) {
    if len(ans) == 0 {
        return
    }
    sort.Slice(ans, func(i, j int) bool {
        return ans[i].Name < ans[j].Name
    })
    for _, node := range ans {
        for i := 0; i < node.Space; i++ {
            fmt.Printf(" ")
        }
        fmt.Println(node.Name)
        sortAndPrint(*node.Children)
    }
}

func findAllNode(ans *[]Node, people map[string]interface{}, space int) {
    ansChild := make([]Node, 0)

    *ans = append(*ans, Node{people["name"].(string), space, &ansChild})
    children, hasChildren := (people["Childs"]).([]interface{})
    if !hasChildren {
        return
    }
    for _, child := range children {
        childMap, ok := child.(map[string]interface{})
        if !ok {
            return
        }
        findAllNode(&ansChild, childMap, space+4)
    }
}

func main() {
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./people.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error:", err)
    }

    var data people

    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(file), &data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error:", err)
    }

    ans := make([]Node, 0)

    for _, value := range data.People {
        value2, ok := value.(map[string]interface{})
        if !ok {
            continue
        }
        findAllNode(&ans, value2, 0)
    }

    sortAndPrint(ans)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's probably simplest to use a json.Decoder.  Also you need to remember that when decoding a JSON map with varying keys (such as "asd", "fda", "fg2" in your example) you should use a map but for fixed keys ("name", "id", "age") you shoudl use a struct.

Here is some code to illustrate [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qmzUFKAM_nF):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type people struct {
    People map[string]Person `json:"people"`
}

type Person struct {
    Name     string   `json:"name"`
    ID       int      `json:"id,omitempty"`
    Sex      string   `json:"s,omitempty"`
    Age      int      `json:"age,omitempty"`
    Children []Person `json:"Childs,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./people.json")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("error:", err)
    }

    var data people
    if err := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(string(file))).Decode(&data); err == nil {
        fmt.Println(data)
    }
}
```